# Django Localization msgmerge error

Tags: python, django, po

I have a medium sized Django project and was using Django Translation . While i run the command `django-admin.py makemessages -l fr` .  I get the below error while using french.

```
CommandError: errors happened while running msgmerge
msgmerge: input file doesn't contain a header entry with a charset specification
```

Where to Specify the charset specification and What to specify in that ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It is just the normal boiler-plate PO-file header. Something like:

```
# SOME DESCRIPTIVE TITLE.
# Copyright (C) YEAR THE PACKAGE'S COPYRIGHT HOLDER
# This file is distributed under the same license as the PACKAGE package.
# FIRST AUTHOR <EMAIL@ADDRESS>, YEAR.
#
#, fuzzy
msgid ""
msgstr ""
"Project-Id-Version: PACKAGE VERSION\n"
"Report-Msgid-Bugs-To: \n"
"POT-Creation-Date: 2014-05-18 20:44+0200\n"
"PO-Revision-Date: YEAR-MO-DA HO:MI+ZONE\n"
"Last-Translator: FULL NAME <EMAIL@ADDRESS>\n"
"Language-Team: LANGUAGE <LL@li.org>\n"
"Language: \n"
"MIME-Version: 1.0\n"
"Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8\n"
"Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit\n"
"Plural-Forms: nplurals=2; plural=(n != 1)\n"
```

You should probably look for the header in an existing french PO-file.

The error is probably caused by an app having no internationalized strings.

Comment: Also make sure your editor (eclipse for me) is set to modify the file in UTF-8